# How can I kill a remote process for my app?

Tags: java, android, activity-manager, remote-process

Our app uses this method to kill remote process; but can any other plan can be used? I need this because `getRunningAppProcesses()` may not work.

```
public void killChildProcess() {
    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for(RunningAppProcessInfo procInfo : procInfos) {
        if (procInfo.processName != null && 
                procInfo.processName.equals("package:remote")) {

            Process.killProcess(procInfo.pid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps")` would return the `ps` list of running processes, you could then lookup the pid for the process you wish to kill.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Matt Clark you can do like this

```
Long PID=Runtime.getRuntime()
  .exec("ps -ef|grep 'package:remote'| awk '{ if(NR==2) print ($2)}'")

Runtime.getRuntime.exec("kill -9 "+PID);
```

Comment: thks for your help, maybe i can get my process info by "ps packagename:remote" and get process id /name. it could be more simple?

Comment: ps will just not return only id/name you need to parse the values

Answer (score 0):

Check the process name contains `:remote` then go ahead.

```
    @Override
    public void killRemoteProcess() {
        ActivityManager activityManager =  (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo: runningAppProcesses) {
            if (appProcessInfo.processName.contains(getApplicationInfo().processName + ":remote")) {
                Log.d("Killing active process: " + getApplicationInfo().processName + ":remote");
                android.os.Process.killProcess(appProcessInfo.pid);
            }
        }
    }
```