# Is it possible to kill an activity using another device running the same app using Push Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification

If it is possible to send a signal to kill an activity on a device using the same app from another device.
Similar to a notification and when notification is clicked it opens an activity but in this case I would like to know if it is possible to close an activity without clicking the notification or something of the sort (Should all be done automatically as soon as the app, say receives a notification).

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800316/how-can-i-kill-a-remote-process-for-my-app) might be of help

Comment: do you want to close a particular device's app ?

Comment: Nope, just an activity or have the app return to MainActivity with out having any click interactions, just done autonomously as soon as the app, say receives a notification

Answer (score 0):

Send notification to the device you want to close it's activity and then use interface callback or eventbus to close the activity

here you can check if activity is active

```
 boolean active;

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     active = true;
  } 

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     active = false;
  }
```

Using eventbus

EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  public void onMessageEvent(closeActivityEvent event) {

    if (active)
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Using interface

activityInterface.closeActivity();

```
 @Override
   public void closeActivity() {
    if(active){
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: sending notification would mean the notification would have to be clicked to close the activity right;

Comment: am looking for a solution to do it with out any interaction of sorts from the user

Comment: you don't need any interaction from user.
when you receiving notification onMessageReceived() method is called then you can use eventbus or interface action to finish the activity